# Dockerfile build image unable to find yum downloads

Tags: docker

In my dockerfile I am downloading JDK17, and copying to another directory to build my image. It downloads fine, and when I do an ls, I do see the files. But when I later do an ADD from this location to another location in my container, it does not find the file.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM oraclelinux:9

ENV JAVA_PKG=java-17-openjdk-17.0.4.0.8-2.el9_0.x86_64.rpm \
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default \
    HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxyhost:port \
    HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxyhost:port 

RUN yum install yum-utils
RUN yumdownloader --destdir target/installer java-17-openjdk -y
RUN ls target/installer
RUN ls target
RUN ls
RUN pwd

ADD target/installer/$JAVA_PKG /usr/java/ -> FAILS
```

Docker image run output

```
Step 1/23 : FROM oraclelinux:9
 ---> fa05a8a60339

Step 2/23 : ENV JAVA_PKG=java-17-openjdk-17.0.4.0.8-2.el9_0.x86_64.rpm     JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default     HTTP_PROXY=http://.......
 ---> Running in bdbf6f67cda5

Removing intermediate container bdbf6f67cda5
 ---> 9a522a690d6a

Step 3/23 : RUN yum install yum-utils
 ---> Running in 636d098e505b

Oracle Linux 9 BaseOS Latest  (x86_64)          3.5 MB/s | 3.6 MB     00:01    
Oracle Linux 9 Application Stream Packages (x86 6.2 MB/s | 8.8 MB     00:01    
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Mon Sep 12 17:32:01 2022.
Package yum-utils-4.0.24-4.0.1.el9_0.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

Removing intermediate container 636d098e505b
 ---> 73abef1e3ed6

Step 4/23 : RUN yumdownloader --destdir target/installer java-17-openjdk -y
 ---> Running in cee9d1d620db
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:06 ago on Mon Sep 12 17:32:01 2022.
java-17-openjdk-17.0.4.0.8-2.el9_0.x86_64.rpm   682 kB/s | 244 kB     00:00    
Removing intermediate container cee9d1d620db
 ---> 6ead60b4a32e

Step 5/23 : RUN ls target/installer
 ---> Running in 6ce3fa03457c

java-17-openjdk-17.0.4.0.8-2.el9_0.x86_64.rpm -----> **File is there**

Removing intermediate container 6ce3fa03457c
 ---> 68c624f00c20

Step 6/23 : RUN ls target
 ---> Running in 5e84a200d2d8

installer

Removing intermediate container 5e84a200d2d8
 ---> b531e9c68a19

Step 7/23 : RUN ls
 ---> Running in bb11fddb08bc

afs
....
dev
etc
....
opt
proc
root
...
srv
sys
**target** --------> **It is there**

...

Removing intermediate container bb11fddb08bc
 ---> 7e8da24633f9

Step 8/23 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 3ca7fbfaa1c7

/

Removing intermediate container 3ca7fbfaa1c7
 ---> bcc07f5b27e4

Step 9/23 : ADD target/installer/$JAVA_PKG /usr/java/
```

this Step 9 here fails with error:

```
ADD failed: stat/scratch/docker/tmp/docker-builder814075534/target/installer/java-17-openjdk-17.0.4.0.8-2.el9_0.x86_64.rpm: no such file or directory
```

Why is it looking in this directory? When I do pwd I am in a "/" directory. ls shows me correct path too. How do I make docker image find my downloaded file?

Appreciate your help
thanks

Comment: Looks like the target is there but then the node with the target gets removed after step 7. You need to handover parameters and tell Docker that you want a file from that container before removing it e.g something like `COPY --from=`. See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

ADD is for adding something from local to docker image.

Try,

```
RUN cp target/installer/$JAVA_PKG /usr/java/
```

Comment: that worked. thank you very much. What is the difference between copying from local (ADD) to cp from downloaded location?

Comment: `ADD` (or, better, `COPY`) copies content from your host system into the image.  `RUN cp ...` copies content within an image.

Comment: Those files are not downloaded into your local directory where you are running the command, rather exist only inside the context of the build. So, ADD command won't work as you are expecting it to be. ADD/COPY is for copying files to that build context from your local machine.  RUN command is to perform some operation inside the build context. In your dockerfile, you are downloading jdk and later copying it to some other path. So, here the operation is being performed upon the build context. Thus, RUN is apt command to be used here.

Comment: I am not sure if the `RUN` is running in the container it is supposed to tho, I think `COPY --from=` is the way it should be used within multistage builds, when one artifact is from another layer. But it might not be the case in the specific situation.

Comment: This dockerfile is not using multi stage, well atleast section that is being shared. So there is no intermediate image to copy from.